# How do I limit selection to visible using the "Poly Build" tool?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, retopology

I'm trying to do retopology with the Poly Build tool, but it keeps on wanting to select faces, edges and vertices from the backside.

I don't have this problem with the select tool, only the Poly Build tool. Does anyone know a way to fix this?

[image: Poly Build vertex on other side]

Comment: There are some great add-ons for retopology.  Many rave about Retopoflow.

Comment: Are you in x-ray mode?  In the upper right of the 3D Viewport there's an icon that shows a rectangle behind a rectangle.  If that's selected you are.  Deselect it and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known design flaw discussed [here](https://developer.blender.org/T70055). This problem would be fixed with the [Retopology Overlay](https://developer.blender.org/D5919) that is being worked on. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be getting much attention despite people bumping the thread.

A current workaround would be selecting all front faces, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection, then <kbd>H</kbd> to hide. Doing this every time you move the viewport camera.